# Groovy compiler fails with unexpected token on readObject

Tags: serialization, groovy

My Gradle project has a mix of Java and Groovy classes. All source is under src/main/groovy. One of my Groovy classes contains a Map that I have created from reading a JSON string via `JsonSlurper.parseText()`. This class is marked Serializable.

To avoid a NotSerializableException, I have implemented my own `writeObject()` and `readObject()` methods, but my code is not compiling. I didn't find many Groovy examples, but various [Java references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) and [tutorials](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html) told me to use these signatures:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
    throws IOException
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
```

My class looks like this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

class GroovyJSONMap implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 20150902L

    Map myJSON = [:]

    GroovyJSONMap() {
        //no op
    }

    GroovyJSONMap(String json) {
        if (json) {
            try {
                setJSON(json)
            } catch (any) {
                println "WHOOPS! Not a JSON object...."
                myJSON = ["invalid": true]
            }
        }
    }

    GroovyJSONMap(Map json) {
        if (json) {
            setJSON(json)
        }
    }

    final void setJSON(String json) {
        myJSON = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
    }

    String getJSON() {
        new JsonBuilder(myJSON).toString()
    }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        getJSON()
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        setJSON((String)in.readObject())
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.writeObject(getJSON())
    }
}
```

The compiler error:

```
:clean
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy
startup failed:
c:\path\to\src\main\groovy\GroovyJSONMap.groovy: 44: unexpected token: ObjectInputStream @ line 110, column 29.
       private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
                               ^

1 error

:compileGroovy FAILED
```

I have moved the `readObject()` method to various positions in the source, but it still is not compiling. The compiler does not complain about `writeObject()`, only `readObject()`. Why is my code not compiling?

Comment: I am asking and self-answering this question because I searched everywhere and did not see this simple answer. I hope it will help the next Java programmer who is starting to use Groovy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler points to `ObjectOutputStream`, but the problem is really at `in`.

The word [in](http://www.groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_different_keywords) is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57471_01/bigData.100/extensions_bdd/src/rext_transform_unsupported_features.html) in Groovy and cannot be used for a variable or method name.

The solution is to rename `in` to any non-Groovy-reserved word, such as `stream` (also changed `writeObject()` for consistency):

```
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    setJSON((String)stream.readObject())
}

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
    stream.writeObject(getJSON())
}
```